# Opto coupler output current

Tags: opto-isolator, spdt

I am trying to drive [R570412030](https://radiall-files.s3.amazonaws.com/tds/ramses/R570412030.pdf) SPDT switch using opto-coupler [LTV206](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/239/LTV-200-1175514.pdf). I am attaching the setup as shown below:

[image]

When ever the 3.3 V (control signal) triggers the opto-coupler, the SPDT will be turned on.

How do I calculate the output current?

Is the output current from opto-coupler is sufficient to drive SPDT switch?

Comment: your schematic makes no sense; as shown, the Optocoupler does nothing. You'll have to connect "7" somewhere. also, you've got two datasheets, one telling you how much current the microwave switch draws, and one how much the optocoupler can pass. So, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I updated the snapshot. What is the maximum output current from optocoupler? I am unable to get it from the datasheet of it

Comment: ah! That shifts the question!

Comment: Removing the unrelated [tag:debugging] tag.

Comment: What's the series resistance on the LED side that you omitted in your diagram (or, more generally, what's the current  you're running through the LED)? And, you might be able to answer this all yourself (in that case, feel encouraged to actually write an answer below – answering your own questions is very welcome here!): Do you understand what the *current transfer ratio* of an optocoupler is?

Comment: The R570412030 is a **relay**, not a switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This opto will not work, at least by itself. It needs an external buffer. You can make one with an NPN transistor.

Optocouplers have a parameter in the datasheet called *current transfer ratio*, or CTR. This states how much current you can expect on the output for a given input LED current.

Your relay needs a lot of current - 250mA. This opto has guaranteed CTR of no better than 100%. Assuming 100% CTR, and an LED current of 10mA (see the Test Conditions) that limits the output current to just 10mA. So, not even close.

Adding a gain buffer will boost the output current and also reduce the required LED current.

Comment: What @hacksital said AND put a flyback diode across the coil.